# How to use Flow with React.createRef()?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Since React 16.3 it is possible to use [`React.createRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access a DOM element. I am also using [Flow](https://flow.org/en/) in my project, but the [documentation still uses the old way](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/refs/).

The below code unfortunately fails:

```js
/* @flow */
import * as React from 'react';

export class TestComponent extends React.Component<{}> {
  myRef: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

with the following error:

```
Cannot instantiate `Ref` because in type argument `ElementType`:
 - Either a callable signature is missing in `HTMLDivElement` [1] but exists in
   `React.StatelessFunctionalComponent` [2].
 - Or `HTMLDivElement` [1] is incompatible with statics of `React.Component` [3].
```

How do I type it correctly?

Comment: https://devdocs.io/flow/react/types#toc-react-ref

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking at the flow type definition for [React.createRef()](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L226):

```js
declare export function createRef<ElementType: React$ElementType>(
): {current: null | React$ElementRef<ElementType>};
```

I was able to do something like this:

```js
/* @flow */
import * as React from 'react';

export class TestComponent extends React.Component<{}> {
  myRef: { current: null | HTMLDivElement }

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create your own generic type to make declarations shorter: type RefType<T> = {
  current: null | T
};
 Then you can use it like this in your class: myRef: ReactRef<HTMLDivElement>

Answer (score 3):

There is a related [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12553).

If it's not fixed yet you can type it yourself:

```
type RefObject = {|
  current: any,
|};
```

This is how it is typed internally in [react library type definitions](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/shared/ReactTypes.js#L103).

Comment: When trying to use the self defined RefObject I get the error `Cannot assign React.createRef() to this.myRef because inexact object type [1] is incompatible with exact
RefObject [2].`  Any idea? (I am quite new to flow).

Comment: @Zardoz try like this: `type RefObject = { current: any };`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "class properties", you may `createRef()` in the following way:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

export class TestComponent extends React.Component<{}> {
  myRef = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using formik reference

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import { Formik } from "formik"


export class TestComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
   formikRef = React.createRef<Formik>();

  render() {
     return (
         <Formik 
            ...,
            ref={this.formikRef}
         />
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the type arrows here fixed it: `const formRef = React.useRef<?HTMLFormElement>(null);`